# numpy - dynamic slicing using mix of all() and any()

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to slice a point cloud numpy array dynamically. The slicing would filter points that x/y coordinates fall inside a list of boundaries defined by `minx`, `miny`, `maxx`, `maxy`

I thought I had a working algorithm but Im facing the `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

For instance (this is only demo data):

```
import numpy as np

bounds_list = [
  (0, 0, 5, 5),
  (8, 8, 10, 10)
]

#col0 --> x , col1 -->  y , col2 --> z
random_arr = np.array([10, 10, 100]) * np.random.rand(100, 3)


def filter_by_bounds(arr):
  slices = np.array([np.array([bounds[0] <= arr[0] <= bounds[2], bounds[1] <= arr[1] <= bounds[3]]).all() for bounds in bounds_list]).any()
  return arr[slices]


filtered_arr = filter_by_bounds(random_arr)
print(filtered_arr)
```

In this demo, I would like to retrieve all points where their x/y coordinates are within at least one of the bounds

Comment: Can you include enough input data so that others can run this?

Comment: I have modified the question to use a random dataset

Comment: `bounds[0] <= arr[0] <= bounds[2]` is native Python and doesn't apply to numpy array, in this case, a point `[x,y,z]`.

Comment: In `python/numpy` `slice` has a technical definition, the object created by `start:stop:step` syntax.  Looks like you are attempting `advanced indexing`, with either numeric index arrays, or boolean arrays.  When asking about an error like this, show the full error message, so we (and you) are clear as to what operation is raising this `ambiguity` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter it like this:

```
def filter_by_bounds(arr):
    x = random_arr[:, 0]
    y = random_arr[:, 1]
    include = np.full(arr.shape[0], False)
    for bounds in bounds_list:
        include |= (bounds[0] <= x) & (x <= bounds[2]) & (bounds[1] <= y) & (y <= bounds[3])
    return arr[include]
```

This includes any point which matches some bound. It uses vectorization to search for matching points.

Comment: Not sure why, but that function returns the whole array unfiltered.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Are you using the example dataset you posted? It generates x and y values between 0 and 1, which will always be contained within the bound 0 to 5.

Comment: you are right, I should replace the random dataset by this: `random_arr = np.array([10, 10, 100]) * np.random.rand(100, 3)`

Comment: The inside for loop can be better done with a broadcast

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm not sure I follow. It is using broadcasting.

Comment: I mean `for bounds in bounds_list:` should/could  be replaced by an numpy operation.